# Show div based on drop down value

Tags: magento2, javascript, drop-downs

Somethings missing and I can't figure out what. I just need to show a div when the drop down Canada is selected. JS code is at the bottom of this. Any ideas? Thanks

```
<div class="field" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses" name="shippingAddress.country_id">

    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: { for: element.uid }" for="B5B0SUM">
        <!-- ko if: element.label -->
        <span data-bind="text: element.label">Country</span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </label>

    <div class="control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': element.tooltip}">
        <!-- ko ifnot: element.hasAddons() -->
            <!-- ko template: element.elementTmpl -->
<select class="select" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label',
    optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
        if (item &amp;&amp; item.disabled) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {attr: {disabled: true}}, item);
        }
    }" name="country_id" id="B5B0SUM" aria-describedby="notice-B5B0SUM" placeholder=""><option value=""> </option><option data-title="" value=""></option><option data-title="Australia" value="AU">Australia</option><option data-title="Austria" value="AT">Austria</option><option data-title="Belgium" value="BE">Belgium</option><option data-title="Canada" value="CA">Canada</option><option data-title="Czech Republic" value="CZ">Czech Republic</option><option data-title="Denmark" value="DK">Denmark</option><option data-title="Ecuador" value="EC">Ecuador</option><option data-title="Finland" value="FI">Finland</option><option data-title="France" value="FR">France</option><option data-title="Germany" value="DE">Germany</option><option data-title="Greece" value="GR">Greece</option><option data-title="Greenland" value="GL">Greenland</option><option data-title="Hungary" value="HU">Hungary</option><option data-title="Iceland" value="IS">Iceland</option><option data-title="Ireland" value="IE">Ireland</option><option data-title="Israel" value="IL">Israel</option><option data-title="Italy" value="IT">Italy</option><option data-title="Japan" value="JP">Japan</option><option data-title="Mexico" value="MX">Mexico</option><option data-title="Netherlands" value="NL">Netherlands</option><option data-title="New Zealand" value="NZ">New Zealand</option><option data-title="North Korea" value="KP">North Korea</option><option data-title="Norway" value="NO">Norway</option><option data-title="Peru" value="PE">Peru</option><option data-title="Poland" value="PL">Poland</option><option data-title="Portugal" value="PT">Portugal</option><option data-title="Qatar" value="QA">Qatar</option><option data-title="Russia" value="RU">Russia</option><option data-title="Saudi Arabia" value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option><option data-title="Singapore" value="SG">Singapore</option><option data-title="South Korea" value="KR">South Korea</option><option data-title="Spain" value="ES">Spain</option><option data-title="Sweden" value="SE">Sweden</option><option data-title="Switzerland" value="CH">Switzerland</option><option data-title="United Kingdom" value="GB">United Kingdom</option><option data-title="United States" value="US">United States</option><option data-title="U.S. Outlying Islands" value="UM">U.S. Outlying Islands</option><option data-title="U.S. Virgin Islands" value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option></select>
<!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: element.hasAddons() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: element.tooltip --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: element.notice --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: element.error() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: element.warn() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>



              <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
CUSTOMS FEES MAY APPLY
              </div>



<script>
 function show(value) {
    if (value == "CA") {
    hiddenDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    Form.fileURL.focus();
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: where did you call show function? on which event you have called show() javascript function?

Comment: On value which in this case the value would be "CA". I guess doing it with data-title="Canada" would work also.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I think you should call jquery on select change(value) and match the selected value & display that div. Please let me know still you have any doubt?